# Display only map key from List<Map<String, List<String>>>

Tags: java, arrays, list, hashmap, key-value

I have the following structure:

```
List<Map<String, List<String>>> filters
```

Consider the following example:

```
filters=[{product=[A1, A2, A3]}]
```

I want to display just the map key and not the values.

Expected output :

```
product
```

I tried the following:

```
String op = filters.get(i).keySet().toString();
```

This gives me the following output:

```
[product]
```

I tried using .stream() as well but that didn't work. I just want to display the keys(one or many) i.e. in this case : product

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If input is `[{a:[1], b:[2]}, {a:[3], c:[4]}]` what should output be? `[[a, b], [a, c]]` or `[a, b, a, c]` or `[a, b, c]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
List<String> collect = filters.stream()
                              .flatMap(entry -> 
                                           entry.keySet().stream())
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

collect will have all the keys of the map.

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

```
filters.stream().flatMap(c -> c.keySet().stream())
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Edit:

> I want to pass the output received example: (product) to another
>   function. Would that be done in the .forEach part? I don't want to
>   print it there

No instead in this case you can collect the result in a List then return it for example :

```
public List<String> myFunction(List<Map<String, List<String>>> filters){
    return filters.stream()
            .flatMap(c -> c.keySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then you can consume it like this :

```
List<String> result = myFunction(filters);
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I want to pass the output received example: (product) to another function. Would that be done in the .forEach part? I don't want to print it there. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TeeJay no instead collect all the results and return it I edit my answer check it